# not able to display Max salary from table (test)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, max, min

I have a table, from which I am unable to select max salary.
Here is my code...

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(salary) AS MAximumSalary FROM test", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(dt);
count =Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Maximum salary is" +count);
```

Here is my database:-

```
name     salary
a       10000
b       31000
c       17000
```

Comment: Because you displaying datatable ROWS COUNT. By the way count is integer and you converting it to string and then back to integer - makes no sense.

Comment: You want ExecuteScalar() not ExecuteNonQuery() and a DataTable/Adapter

Comment: Doesn't it have to be a MySqlDataAdapter if this is using a MySQL database? Haven't worked with MySQL database for quite a long time, though (despite the fact that he should go scalar anyway).

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["MAximumSalary"])` will also give you the expected result.

Comment: thank you all, it's working now ….

Comment: is there any change in code required for AVG(salary) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(salary) FROM test"), con)
{
    int maxSalary = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT max(salary) FROM test"), con);
count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Maximum salary is" +count);
```